# Aggregating results based on three variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'date': ['2021-03-15', '2021-03-15', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-12', '2021-03-12', '2021-12-14', '2021-04-07', '2021-07-09', '2021-04-25', '2021-04-25'],
'n': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
'type': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
't': [1.41, 1.05, 2.01, 0.79, 1.37, 2.19, 1.28, 1.9, 0.97, 1.48, 1.96],
'leq': [73.95284344, 75.08732477, 42.52073186, 14.16069694, 59.36296547, 48.7827182, 44.48691532, 63.63032644, 95.20787662, 61.38061937, 12.50041565]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and would like to aggregate the values based on three variables id, date and type using the formula below

[image]

In other words, the aggregation will encompass the three variables

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly should they be grouped? A unique row for every unique tuple of `(id, date, leq)`? Even if so, `leq` is non-categorical so how should the numeric data be binned? In addition, what kind of aggregation should be applied: sum/mean? Ideally, you provide the desired output table so we can reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a direct application of `groupby` and your mathematical formula:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'date', 'type'])\
  .apply(lambda s: 10 * np.log(1/(s['t'].sum()) * np.sum(s['t'] * (10**(s['leq']/10)))))

id  date        type
1   2021-03-15  A       171.482002
    2021-03-17  B        94.598488
2   2021-03-12  B       128.447851
    2021-12-14  B       102.434908
3   2021-04-07  B       146.514241
    2021-04-25  A        28.783271
                B       141.334099
    2021-07-09  A       219.224237
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. It works perfectly! Quick question - is it possible to have the new columns in the original dataframe rather than having a collapsed dataframe? Thanks!

Comment: @StephenOkiya You can simply merge back using `.merge`: `df.merge(...)` where `...` is the output above. You might need to `...`.reset_index() before merging.